# How to make a phone call from Apple watch?

Tags: ios, phone-call, watchkit

Is there a way to make phone calls from `WatchKit` extension?

Below is my code.

```
NSExtensionContext *ctx = [[NSExtensionContext alloc] init];
NSString *cleanedString = [[@"1234567890" componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789-+()"] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSURL *telURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", cleanedString]];
[ctx openURL:telURL completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
    NSLog(@"fun=%s after completion. success=%d", __func__, success);
}];
```

Comment: Apple Watch still not available, so there is no way to test it. Right now only in simulator I could test.

Comment: This would be a better question to ask in the confidential Apple Developer Forums for WatchKit, where you might actually get a definitive answer from an Apple employee if you ask nicely. :)

Comment: Sure @DuncanBabbage I have already asked the same question and got the answer that its not possible as there is no api to perform this feature as of now. The alternative they mentioned was to implement "handoff".

Comment: Its not working for me. Code exudes properly no error but does nothing.