# How to programmatically make phone call from apple watch app?

Tags: xcode, apple-watch, swift2

My Watch app has list of contact and I want open initiate call from watch. like we do in iPhone device.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27730688/how-to-make-a-phone-call-from-apple-watch) solution but not working for.

Comment: One of the comments in the post you link states that what you're asking for is not possible. Do you have some reason to think otherwise? If you do, I suggest you get a bit more specific with what you've tried, including code that fails and an explanation of what fails. Without that, your question is insufficient and likely to be closed.

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed it using following method

```
var phone = "123456"
if let telURL=NSURL(string:"tel:\(phone)") {
    let wkExt=WKExtension.sharedExtension()
    wkExtension.openSystemURL(telURL)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4 / WatchOS 5**

```
var phone = "1234567890"
if let telURL = URL(string: "tel:\(phone)") {
    let wkExt = WKExtension.shared()
    wkExt.openSystemURL(telURL)
}
```